# what's the recommended practice for using doctrine/data-fixtures with Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpunit, zf3

Just thought I'd take the liberty of asking before I start banging my head on the desk. I'm aware of https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures, and in a ZF2 project I have used it following the pattern found at https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/using-doctrine-data-fixture-for-testing-querybuilder-inside-repository/

But before diving in and attempting the same with ZF3 I wonder if anyone has any experience to share. Thanks.

Comment: Some months later... how'd you go?

Comment: really well, in fact. maybe I should post an actual Answer. I borrowed from https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/using-doctrine-data-fixture-for-testing-querybuilder-inside-repository/ and found that it works about the same with ZF3. if there were any complications, I no longer remember what they were.

By way of example, there is https://github.com/davidmintz/court-interpreters-office/tree/master/module/InterpretersOffice/test